# How to extract Oracle 3.x data from really old server

Tags: database, oracle

tl;dr - How can I extract database information from an Oracle 3.x database server when the tools today don't support it?

I have a customer who neglected upgrades across the board (Win Server 2003, Oracle 3x, etc..yes, I know this is wrong across the board but It's my job to clean it up) and I need to extract the database information from the databases on this server for importing into something more modern.

I've checked the Oracle and non oracle db GUI applications and they oldest they go back is version 7.  I've looked on Google and here and I have yet to find some sort of solution for data extraction.  Do I need to ping Oracle for a version of their Gui application that will work with Version 3?  Is there a code solution?  I'm stumped.

Comment: Oracle **3**? It dates from 1983. I wouldn't put my money on any GUI that supports it. But, SQL*Plus should work. Though, I don't know whether it supported `spool` so that you could export rows from those tables. I'm afraid you have a problem, and I don't know anyone who can help you solve it. Sorry.

Comment: I assume for an Oracle **3** (really crazy) database the amount of data is very small, so try to export data to plain CSV file and import to new system. Trigger, Foreign Keys, PL/SQL did not exist these days, so there is nothing you could loose.

Comment: @Littlefoot That did the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick @littlefoot I also looked at the following:

SQuirrel

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=faq

SQLTools

http://www.sqltools.net/